# Boost Mutex implementation for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, boost

As far as I know in old versions of Boost `boost::mutex` implementation for Windows was done using critical sections. But in the newest version of Boost 1.51 I discovered that now mutex implementation is based on Events.

Does anybody know what is the rational behind this change? Was it done because of performance reasons? Do critical sections become deprecated?

Comment: Did you look at boosts changelogs?

Comment: As far as I can see, it was done to simplify and unify the design of various mutexes: currently `mutex`, `timed_mutex`, `try_mutex` - are all implemented using `detail::basic_timed_mutex`, which can't use CS. (Actually, using CS is not always the best choice, it depends on concurrency scenario, so it's not worth complicating design for that.)

Comment: You do realize that only the designers of boost can fully answer this. The rest of us can only speculate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it wonderful that by using `boost` we always have best approach with no change?
In new version of `boost`, `boost::mutex` is implemented as an spinlock but with the help of a windows event to avoid busy wait and that event will only created if needed, thus it is very light weight and have a very high performance and also enable `boost` to use this light weight `mutex` for timed wait! I think this is excellent

Comment: @Benj and who told that we need a true spinlock here? Many parts of `boost` depend on spinlock that implemented using atomic variables, for example take a look at implementation of `boost::shared_ptr` and `boost::detail::spinlock` and write a small program that compare performance of that spinlock implementation with fastest lock that implemented on windows and even *nix systems and you see that result is wonderful!

Comment: You are almost correct, but actually `boost::mutex` does not use spinlocks at all! It uses atomic ops as an optimization: when acquiring the lock, it will first (atomically) check a variable that tells whether the mutex is currently locked. If not locked, then it can continue (without having to consider the win32 event at all), thats the fast path. If the check said that the mutex is locked, then the (more) costly win32 stuff comes into play. But here no spinlocks at all ;-)