# Boost mutex: spin-lock or kernel mutex?

Tags: c++, boost

How does the C++ Boost library's mutex class work underneath? Is it a spin-lock that remains in user space, or a kernel-allocated lock?

Comment: This is clearly going to be OS specific. Which OS(es) do you have in mind?

Comment: Look at the description:http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/mutex.html

Comment: @NPE I'm most interested in Windows, but any additional info on other OSes is welcome.

Comment: @user2183287 I see that it maps to a CRITICAL_SECTION on Windows, but given that I'm not familiar with it, I can't deduce the answer to my own question (even after reading the MSDN documentation about it).

Comment: there is something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014635/boost-mutex-implementation-for-windows

Comment: According to that Q&A, in my case it must be a kernel lock, since I have Boost 1.47.